# Linear regression, numerical integration and non-specific fitting

Tags: fitting

I am still pretty new to Mathematica.

I am numerically integrating a function that we can consider as
`NIntegrate[f[z] g[z], {z, 0, 1}]` so that, when I put in what I think `f[z]` is, it gives me a curve that looks like the following:

[image]

I want the output to be a straight line and do not care, nor know, the values at the end points. I need a straight line from some positive value at the left to the negative of that number on the right.

My plan is to replace `f[z]` with a polynomial of the needed order and have Mathematica iterate for best fit. Changing the fitting parameters will change the intercept and slope and I do not have target values for these.

Comment: Kinda hard to answer with so little information. Can you show the `f[z]` and `g[z]` that you used to generate the figure?

Comment: Sure. F[z] is currently (1-2z0) and I plan to replace as a polynomial, unsure of the order. g[z] is messier... NIntegrate[(k1 + k2 z0 + k3 z0^2) ArcSin[
   2 a/(\[Sqrt]((r + a)^2 + (z0 - z)^2) + \[Sqrt]((r - a)^2 + (z0 - 
             z)^2))], {z0, 0, l}]   The f[z] is the polynomial in z0 and the k's are the fitting constants, I may need higher order. a is a constant, the answer is a function of r & z. For the fit I am fixing r=a and I want to fit to a straight line in z.